# Guideliness to achieve push notification in android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification

I am doing Cross platform application, my current work is going on implementing push notification. I can able to see the message acknowledgment was positive from server.

```
MessageResult:MulticastResult(multicast_id=somenumber,total=1,success=1.failure=0.canonical_ids=0,results:[[messageID=somenumber]])
```

Here `success=1` message was successfully pushed to `GCM` server but for `IOS` its not an issue.

Once in a while i am getting notification. I cant track in which area is going wrong either with my mobile data or GCM. Any techies have faced this scenario ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.mobile"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.company.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.company.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.company.mobile.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.company.mobile.ScreenOrientation" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.company.mobile.monitor" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your client code and manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the couple of days i found out the issue and came up with solution. The GCM is reliable one the only problem is with device. We need to check

- If you using Wi-Fi consult your network admin whether the push notification port is enable.
- If you are using mobile data check the settings of the device which enable for push notification. (Settings -- > WiFi -->Data usage --> Your application(enable notification))
- Need to check whether google account is properly synched. (This scenario created issue in my case)
- Don't switch between mobile data and Wi-Fi.
- Finally restart the device.

Some tips [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/B1aIj02W4Ao)